# Printing value of custom attributes on multiple divs

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am working on a Shopify store where there are multiple divs like below:

```
<div class="options-selection__option-values" data-variant-option="" data-variant-option-index="0" data-variant-option-chosen-value="One"></div>

<div class="options-selection__option-values" data-variant-option="" data-variant-option-index="0" data-variant-option-chosen-value="Two">

<div class="options-selection__option-values" data-variant-option="" data-variant-option-index="0" data-variant-option-chosen-value="Three">

<div class="options-selection__option-values" data-variant-option="" data-variant-option-index="0" data-variant-option-chosen-value="Four">
```

I want to get the value of custom attribute `data-variant-option-chosen-value`and print that into `<span class="selected-variant"></span>`

I tried reading the custom attribute value by following jQuery without any success

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.options-selection__option-values').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('data-variant-option-chosen-value'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the value of attribute using `$(this).attr("data-variant-option-chosen-value")`, concatenate it, set it to the required target.

Also your template and script has some errors. divs missing closing tag and the `$(document).ready(function () {` missing the cloaing tag

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  let val = ''
  $(".options-selection__option-values").each(function () {
    val += $(this).attr("data-variant-option-chosen-value");
  });
  $(".selected-variant").text(val)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="selected-variant"></span>
<div
  class="options-selection__option-values"
  data-variant-option=""
  data-variant-option-index="0"
  data-variant-option-chosen-value="One"
></div>

<div
  class="options-selection__option-values"
  data-variant-option=""
  data-variant-option-index="0"
  data-variant-option-chosen-value="Two"
></div>

<div
  class="options-selection__option-values"
  data-variant-option=""
  data-variant-option-index="0"
  data-variant-option-chosen-value="Three"
></div>

<div
  class="options-selection__option-values"
  data-variant-option=""
  data-variant-option-index="0"
  data-variant-option-chosen-value="Four"
></div>
```

Comment: Thanks it's working now, any way to add a seperator between each value and detect the value on .change()?

Comment: @BilalNaseer do you not know how to concatenate strings?   `+ ", "`? If not, I feel you would benefit from reading some basic javascript tutorials.

Comment: Sorry I was not able to make myself clear, so we are printing value in ``` $(".selected-variant").text(val)``` but it's showing it like this OneTwoThreeFour. Can we add something in the code to display it like One / Two / Three / Four

Comment: Nevermind I found the way .get().join('/') does the trick. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine, you just have syntax error, you are missing "})" at the end and it throws the error  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"`

As of now, you are not closing neither the anonymous callback function, neither the ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.options-selection__option-values').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('data-variant-option-chosen-value'));
});
})
```